# В коде возникает ошибка CS0161 "ResetCanShootCoroutine"(не все пути кода возвращают значение)

Tags: c#

```
    public void Shoot()
    {
        if(_canShoot)
        {
            PerformShoot();
            _canShoot = false;
            StartCoroutine(routine:ResetCanShootCoroutine());
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator ResetCanShootCoroutine()
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил коментариев

```html
public void Shoot() { 
  if(_canShoot) { 
    PerformShoot(); 
    _canShoot = false; 
    StartCoroutine(routine:ResetCanShootCoroutine()); 
  } 
  // что возращать имз метода в случае _canShoot != true
} 

private IEnumerator ResetCanShootCoroutine() {
 /// ???? сюда нужно что нибуть имплементировать и вернуть результат IEnumerator???
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerator` - интерфейс.

`IEnumerator` обычно используется с циклом, и должен возвращать экземпляр класса, который реализует `IEnumerator`.